# Convert a CSV file into JSON [BUG]

Tags: php, json, csv

I would like to create a JSON file with my CSV file.

But I get an error with the function array_combine.
How  could i fix that please?

Here is the **code**:

```
function csvtojson($file,$delimiter)
{
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) === false)
    {
            die("can't open the file.");
    }

    $csv_headers = fgetcsv($handle, 4000, $delimiter);
    $csv_json = array();

    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4000, $delimiter))
    {
            $csv_json[] = array_combine($csv_headers, $row);
    }

    fclose($handle);
    return json_encode($csv_json);}
```

Here is the **error**:

> Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number
>   of elements in /var/www/inae-obs/app/controllers/csvToJson.php on line
>   15

Comment: What error? What's happening that shouldn't be? What are you seeing vs what are you expecting? etc.

Comment: That `enter code here` part is from SO pasting, right?

Comment: Okay, so what part of that error message are you not understanding?

Comment: I understand the message, but i would to fix this error.
If i'm not wrong, the message said that the number of value of both array are different

Comment: There's nothing stopping a CSV file from having rows with differing numbers  of columns.  I guess one of your rows has more columns than the first row.  It's up to you to take that into account when parsing them.

Comment: Yes that's right, I have some lines with 10 columns and sometimes 20 or more ...
But how could i fix that ?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Check if the row's column count matches header column not and if not [fill it](http://php.net/array_pad) with empty array items so the error will never occur.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer you think it's right. We are expecting this from you. Don't just ask and go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `array_combine` method to overcome this:

```
<?php 

function array_combine_custom($keys, $values){
    $combined = [];
    $keys_values = array_values($keys);
    $values_values = array_values($keys);
    foreach($keys_values as $index => $key){
        $combined[$key] = isset($values_values[$index]) ? $values_values[$index] : null;
    }
    return $combined;
}
```

**if the keys and values are in order** and you are OK with ignoring the rest.